# SSO flow using Spring authorization server + Spring boot 3.0.4 + Google

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, single-sign-on, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying to understand the flow of a SSO with any provider (in this case Google).
I implemented an authorization server using Spring boot 3 and Spring authorization server version 1.0.0.

Authorize/token endpoints work well and i get my JWT as expected with all the extra claims i've added.
Above every API i have the following annotation:
`@RolesAllowed({"ADMIN"})`

I'm now trying to add the SSO functionality in order for users to sign-up/login via Google. I've defined my application in Google, added to application.yaml the relevant information: private,public,redirect-uri and added in my SecurityConfig class:

```
 @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/v1/sign-up/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder)
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(customJwtAuthenticationConverter())
                .and()
                .and()
                .formLogin(c ->
                        c.defaultSuccessUrl("/my-ui/index.html"))
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userService(oauthUserService)
                .and()
                .successHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                    CustomOAuth2User oauthUser = (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
                    response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/my-ui/index.html");
                    });

        return http.build();
    }
```

My CustomOAuth2UserService.java:

```
@Service
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User user = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        return new CustomOAuth2User(user);
    }
}
```

I succeed to perform the login but when i try to run any of the APIs i fail because when i try to check the permissions i don't have them ofcourse because this is not my JWT token with extra claims and because the token initiated is OAuth2AuthenticationToken and not JWTAuthenticationToken.

My questions:

1. Do i need to create my JWT after the user signed up/login using SSO?
2. How can this be done if i didn't implement the JWT encoding? I don't want to implement something different than how Spring does it behind the scenes. I don't want 2 implementations.
3. If #1 is true, after creating the JWT, how do i return it to the user?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions for now..

I added to my user entity `implements OAuth2User` as well as UserDetails.
Now, when authentication succeeds, the returned principal is my user which contains all the roles and scopes needed.